# Symfony2 SonataPageBundle - Catchable Fatal Error - Snapshot::setPage()

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have been using Symfony2 for a while now, and I recently added FOSUserBundle, SonataAdminBundle, and then SonataPageBundle.

Everything was working fine until, after adding SonataPageBundle, I tried to use the Admin Dashboard to click on "Add New" in the Snapshot section. It gave the following error when trying to load the page:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Sonata\PageBundle\Model\Snapshot::setPage() must be an instance of
>   Sonata\PageBundle\Model\PageInterface, null given, called in
>   Symfony/vendor/bundles/Sonata/PageBundle/Controller/SnapshotAdminController.php
>   on line 38 and defined in
>   Symfony/vendor/bundles/Sonata/PageBundle/Model/Snapshot.php line 236
>   500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException

I know that there is was an error with `SetPage()` but this has apparently been fixed, and I checked the the code against the commit. Other than adding an Admin user and a Test user, all the bundles are still as they were when installed.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This was solved by rande on Github   https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/issues/21